# How to return multiple rows in sqlalchemy based on value of a column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some `table` in a database that looks like that:

```
phase_type phase_start phase_end
Obsolete   01/01/2021  02/02/2022
Obsolete   01/03/2021  02/07/2022
Obsolete   05/01/2021  09/02/2022
Available  05/07/2021  09/02/2027
Available  05/07/2023  09/02/2025
Available  05/07/2024  09/02/2029
```

If I want to `select` on this `table` and return only the rows that the date of today is lying between the range of 30 days in the past of `phase_end`, I could do like this:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
fromo sqlalchemy import select

past   = my_table.phase_end - timedelta(30)
future = my_table.phase_end

query = select(my_table).where(date.today() >= past,date.today() <= future)

session.exec(query).fetchall()
```

However I would like to use `phase_start` when calculating `past` and `future` for the case when `phase_type` is `Obsolete`, for all the other cases I would like to use `phase_end` as above. Thus the range should be calculated based on the value that `phase_end` takes. How can I do this and return all rows that pass the conditions ?

Comment: What is the type of the start and end columns in the database?

Comment: Is of date type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to return rows that meet the specified conditions, you can use a `case` statement in the `where` clause of your `select` query.

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
from sqlalchemy import case, select

past = case([(my_table.phase_type == 'Obsolete', my_table.phase_start)], else_=my_table.phase_end) - timedelta(30)
future = case([(my_table.phase_type == 'Obsolete', my_table.phase_start)], else_=my_table.phase_end)

query = select(my_table).where(date.today() >= past,date.today() <= future)

session.exec(query).fetchall()
```

This query will return all rows from `my_table` where `date.today()` falls within the range of 30 days in the past of either `phase_start` (if `phase_type` is `Obsolete`) or `phase_end` (for all other cases).

Comment: Why do you use a list of tuples wrapped around `case`? I saw an example of `case` in sql alchemy docs with just a tuple